# Adding path location column when concatenating multiple csv in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list of paths with multiple CSV's of the same shape called `routes`

to read this into a single Spark Data Frame I use :

```
df = spark.read.option("header","true").format('csv').load(routes)
```

routes is a list of DBFS paths. When running the above is it possible to add a column with the path so I know where the data came from?

in pandas i'd do something like `pd.concat(files, keys=routes) # assume files is a list of pandas csv dataframes.`

is there a method to add a column with the route

Naturally I thought you could use `.withColumn('path',routes)` but this throws the following Error :

`AttributeError: 'DataFrameReader' object has no attribute 'withColumn'`

my routes looks like

```
routes = ['dbfs:/mnt/Foo/Day_1`,'dbfs:/mnt/Foo/Day_2`,'dbfs:/mnt/Foo/Day_3`]
```

current df

```
df.show()
col_1 | col_2 | col_3
A     |  1    | 1
B     |  1    | 1
A     |  2    | 2
...
```

expected output

```
col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | path 
A     |  1    | 1     | 'dbfs:/mnt/Foo/Day_1`
B     |  1    | 1     | 'dbfs:/mnt/Foo/Day_2`
A     |  2    | 2     | 'dbfs:/mnt/Foo/Day_3`
...
```

Comment: @ Downvoter care to explain the issue with this question - happy to amend and take feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `input_file_name()` function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name

df.withColumn('path', input_file_name())
```